# How to sort a TreeSet by Value?

Tags: java, sorting, treemap, treeset

I am pretty new to `TreeMap` and `TreeSet` and the likes and was wondering how to sort the data structures by value?  I realise with a TreeSet you can sort it into alphabetical order automatically but I want it to order via value?  Any idea on how to do this?

It currently prints like...

- aaa: 29
- aaahealthart: 30
- ab: 23
- abbey: 14
- abdomin: 3
- aberdeen: 29
- aberdeenuni: 20

When I want it to print like...

- aaahealthart: 30
- aaa: 29
- aberdeen: 29
- ab: 23
- aberdeenuni: 20
- abbey: 14
- abdomin: 3

Here is my method here...

```
ArrayList<String> fullBagOfWords = new ArrayList<String>();
public Map<String, Integer> frequencyOne;

public void termFrequency() throws FileNotFoundException{
    Collections.sort(fullBagOfWords);
    Set<String> unique = new TreeSet<String>(fullBagOfWords);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(frequencyFile));
    pw.println("Words in Tweets :   Frequency of Words");
    for (String key : unique) {
        int frequency = Collections.frequency(fullBagOfWords, key);

        System.out.println(key + ": " + frequency);
        pw.println(key + ": " + frequency);
        }
    pw.close();
    }
```

Thanks for all the help guys.

Comment: You can't. Use a HashMap to store the words and their frequency, then transform the map into a List<Map.Entry>, and sort that list by value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TreeMap` orders by key, I don't think you can use the same implementation to sort by the value. But you can achieve the task with a slightly different approach:

```
public Map<String, Integer> countWords(List<String> words) {
    Map<String, Integer> result = new Map<>();
    for (String word : words) {
        if (result.containsKey(word)) {
            // the word is already in the map, increment the count
            int count = result.get(word) + 1;
            result.put(word, count);
        } else {
            result.put(word, 1);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Then you just need to sort the elements of the resulting map. You can do this in the following way:

```
public List<Map.Entry<String, Integer> sortMap(Map<String, Integer> map) {
    List<Map.Entry<String, Integer> elements = new LinkedList<>(map.entrySet());
    Collections.sort(elements, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>() {

        public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Integer> o1, Map.Entry<String, Integer> o2 ) {
            return o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());
        }

    });
}
```

So you use the first method to count the word frequency and the second to sort by it.

Comment: @and how do I combine the two? Do I just call `result` inside the `sortMap()` method?

Comment: @JohnLewis Yes, you need to take the result from the `countWords()` method and pass it as an argument to the `sortMap()` method.

Comment: @Danial Alexiev -- i don't think the count words works correctly, as I notice word counts are higher than the words appear?

Comment: @JohnLewis That is because you should put 1 when you first encounter a word. Updating my answer now.

Comment: alexia -- but even then, it says theres a word that occurs 9 times when it only occurs like 7? i don't know if thats your code or mine that faults with that though

Comment: @JohnLewis You can try and debug the counting step by step to see what's happening and where is the error coming from. I'm pretty sure the algorithm should work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
Set<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> sorted = 
      new TreeSet<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>>(new Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> {
    public int compare(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> first, Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> second) {
       return first.getValue().compareTo(second.getValue());
    }

    public boolean equals(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> that) {
        return this.equals(that);
    }
});
```

That should give you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an ArrayList and store each entry in it like this:

```
ArrayList<Map.Entry<String, Integer> list = new new ArrayList(map.entrySet());
```

then you can sort the arrayList using a comparator that compares the entries by their value:

```
Collections.sort(list , new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>() {

        public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Integer> o1, Map.Entry<String, Integer> o2 ) {
            return o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());
        }

    });
```

And then you can print the entries from the arrayList